# Allocate memory in one function and use it in another function

Tags: c, reference, dereference

The following code seems to work. gcc 5.2.1 on linux didn't give any warning.

I am a newbie to C. I got this working by writing down what the & and * operators do at each line with English sentences and trial and error.

There are two things that I am not sure.

The initial value of `p0` in line A is unpredictable. Yet, line E assigns a value to the address specified by the value of the variable p0 in main. Will this cause any problem? If so, how to fix that?

The code use so many *, like *** in line C. Can it use less * without getting warning from gcc?

Thank you.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void* f(int*** ptr_p)     //C
{
    int** p = *(ptr_p);   //D
    *p      = malloc(8);  //E
    *(*p)   = 200;        //F
    (*p)[1] = 4;          //G
}

int main(void)
{
    int** p0;             //A
    f(&p0);               //B
    printf("%d, %d\n",*(*p0), (*p0)[1]);
    free(*p0);            //H
}
```

In case if you want to see the English sentences, here they are.

*Warning*: I am a newbie in C, and I don't know if they are all correct.

Line [A]  `int** p0;`

The value of `p0` is unpredictable.

Line [B]  `f(&p0);`

`&p0` is address of variable `p0`. `f(&p0)` means to call function `f` and assign `&p0` to the 1st argument of the function.

Line [C]  `void* f(int*** ptr_p)`

Line B assigns `&p0` to `ptr_p`. This means the value of `ptr_p` is now equal to the address of variable `p0` in the main function.

Line [D]  `int** p = *(ptr_p);`

`*(ptr_p)` means the value at an address specified by the value of `ptr_p`, interpreted as an address. Value of `ptr_p` is address of variable `p0` in the main function, as described in Line C. So, `*(ptr_p)` is value of variable `p0` in the main function.

`p = *(ptr_p);` means assign value of `p0` in the main function to value of `p`

Line [E] `*(p)    = malloc(8);`

`*(p)` means value at an address specified by the value of `p`. Value of `p` is value of the `p0` variable in main, as described in Line [D]. Then, `*(p)` means value of the address specified by the value of the `p0` variable in `main()`.

`malloc(8)` reserves 8 bytes in memory, and return the address of the first of the 8 bytes.

The whole line means to assign the address of the first of these 8 bytes as the value of the address specified by the `p0` variable in `main()`.

Line [F]  `*(*p)   = 200;`

Line [G] `(*p)[1] = 4;`

`(p)[1]` means `*(p + 1)`

`(*p)[1]` means `*(*p + 1)`

Comment: it is 3:10am, I go sleep now. will check answers tomorrow. This seems fun and useful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, line E is a problem. Actually, you are already in trouble at line D, because you read the (undefined) value of `p0`. This is forbidden in C; it is part of the dreaded *undefined behavior*, which means that all bets are off and the compiler is legally allowed to output anything it wants: a binary that crashes, or prints "Hello world!", you name it.

You correctly saw that `p0` should point to an `int *` buffer before you can write in that buffer. However, there is no need for this extra level of indirection. `p0` can be an `int *`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int** ptr_p)     //C
{
    *ptr_p      = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);  //E
    (*ptr_p)[0] = 200;        //F
    (*ptr_p)[1] = 4;          //G
}

int main(void)
{
    int* p0;             //A
    f(&p0);              //B
    printf("%d, %d\n", p0[0], p0[1]);
    free(p0);            //H
    return 0;
}
```

One last thing: `malloc` could fail and return `NULL`; a robust program would check that.

Comment: In the end, I picked your method because I tried to return (pointers to) multiple arrays from the function. The code is used in this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37933956/get-sizes-of-pairwise-intersection-between-sorted-sets-very-efficiently) Thanks.

Comment: @rxu I only chose this style for consistency with your original code. I usually use the return value when there is only one thing to return; and even when there are two or three of them, I sometimes pack them together in a structure that I then return. An optimizing compiler can generate extremely efficient code, especially if the function is `static` (local to the compilation unit, hence not bound by any ABI). In general, not taking the address of a local variable helps the compiler "pull it out of memory", i.e. keep it in CPU registers.

Comment: ah. i will use a structure next time.

Answer (score 2):

You have more stars that you need: the fewer the better, so I have simplified your program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *f(int size)                    // returns a pointer
{
    int *p;                         // define a pointer
    p = malloc(size);               // allocate memory to it
    if(p == NULL) {                 // check the result
        exit(1);                    // emergency exit
    }
    *p = 200;                       // put a value at p[0];
    p[1] = 4;                       // put a value at p[1];
    return p;                       // return the pointer
}

int main(void)
{
    int *p0;                        // pointer as yet has no value assigned
    p0 = f(2 * sizeof *p0);         // get memory for 2 ints and initialise it
    printf("%d, %d\n", *p0, p0[1]); // show the two ints assigned
    free(p0);                       // release the memory
    return 0;                       // end of program
}
```

Program output:

```
200, 4
```

Apart from fewer stars, there are two main changes to your program

1. The function returns a pointer directly. Setting it via an argument requires one more star.
2. The amount of memory requested is for two elements of the data type, not "hard coded".

Also you are correct in thinking there is more than one way you can access an array based on a pointer.

Comment: Amen, a *three-star* function is generally not a compliment for the function (though sometimes it is necessary)

Comment: Thank you for the very clear and clean implementation. The comments are very helpful. I will use this one next time when I only have to return (pointer to) one array from the function.